# Vim: How to insert command into command history?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, ack

I have a mapping where I can select text and type <kbd>(leader)</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to ack for my visual selection with [Ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim):

```
" Visual ack, used to ack for highlighted text
function! s:VAck()
    let old = @"
    norm! gvy
    let @z = substitute(escape(@", '\'), '\n', '\\n', 'g')
    let @" = old
endfunction


" Ack for visual selection
vnoremap <Leader>av :<C-u>call <SID>VAck()<CR>:exe "Ack! ".@z.""<CR>
```

However, I will frequently want to re-ack for the last thing I searched for, so I type <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>up</kbd> to search backwards through my command history for it. Problem is, this method doesn't populate the history!

**My question is** how can I do one of the following:

- Insert an entry into the command line history using Vimscript **-or-**
- Make the command it builds actually execute as a colon command, so history is populated automatically?

I am fully aware of the the `:copen` and `:colder` commands to open and browse to an older quickfix list (which [Ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim) populates), but I would like to know how to solve my above problem because I want to re-ack for the same thing when I know parts of my source code have changed.

Answer (score 10):

When they are part of a mapping, commands are not added to the command history.

Adding an item to a specific history is done with the `histadd()` function:

```
call histadd("cmd", "e $MYVIMRC")
```

See `:help histadd()`.

You could start by making your function return the search pattern instead of clobbering your registers:

```
function! VAck()
    let old = @"
    norm! gvy
    let pat = substitute(escape(@", '\'), '\n', '\\n', 'g')
    let @" = old
    return pat
endfunction
```

which would allow you to simplify your base mapping:

```
vnoremap <Leader>av :<C-u>exe "Ack! " . VAck()<CR>
```

that we now could modify to add the command to the history:

```
vnoremap <Leader>av :<C-u>let cmd = "Ack! " . VAck() <bar> call histadd("cmd", cmd) <bar> execute cmd<CR>
```

where you:

1. build your command, `let cmd = "Ack! " . VAck()`
2. add that command to the history, `call histadd("cmd", cmd)`
3. execute the command, `execute cmd`.

The end result is exactly the same as if you had actually typed `:Ack! foo`.

---

A few comments…

- I think that's a good idea, I'll change my config (I already have similar functions and mappings) accordingly.
- You should use `xnoremap` instead of `vnoremap` to restrain your mapping to actual visual mode.
- In `VAck()`, yanking to the unnamed register will clobber your system clipboard if you have  something like `clipboard=unnamed` in your config. You should use a specific register instead:

  ```
  function! VAck()
      let old = @z
      norm! gv"zy
      let pat = substitute(escape(@z, '\'), '\n', '\\n', 'g')
      let @z = old
      return pat
  endfunction
  ```